# How to add several authors with different affiliations in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

Is it possible to do this in `beamer`? Or do I have to use other packages?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Yes, something along those lines:

```
\author[shortname]{author1 \inst{1} \and author2 \inst{2}}
\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} affiliation for author1 \and %
                      \inst{2} affiliation for author2}
```

See documentation for [Beamer class](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (page 94, v3.10).

Comment: How do you highlight the first author, for example with a underscore?

Comment: @LWZ Not sure I understand what you mean (underscore?), but `\emph{author1}` should work.

Comment: @chl, by underscore I mean have a solid line beneath the name.

Comment: @LWZ Have you tried `\underline{author1}`?

Comment: @chl Although that produces the correct output, Beamer doesn't seem to like it and generates a bunch of hyperref error messages. Each message begins with "Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):"

Comment: Simple but elegant answer!

Comment: What should go in "shortname"? If the authors are named e.g. Emily Riehl and J. Peter May, should we put "E. Riehl \and J. P. May", or something else?

Comment: @CalebStanford You can try `\texorpdfstring{\underline{author1}}{author1}`.

Answer (score 16):

The second solution provides proper use of font for superscripts.

```
\author[shortname]{First Author \textsuperscript{1} \and Second Author \inst{1, 2} \and Fourth Author \inst{2,3}}
\institute[shortinst]{\textsuperscript{1} ITMO University \and \inst{2} University of Whatever \and \inst{3} Whatever Institute}
```

Gives the following -- pay attention to the superscripts font. The first one looks correct.

[image]

Comment: Did anyone try this with the metropolis team? I can't make it work. The superscripts show up, but not the notes with the affiliation, unfortunately.

Comment: It's working for me on the metropolis theme.

Comment: Is it possible to put both institutions on the same line?

Answer (score 6):

Here's another solution:

```
\title{\huge xx}
\author{Author1 \textsuperscript{1,2},Author2 \textsuperscript{1,2,3}}
\institute[A]{\textsuperscript{1}Dep of X\\ %
\textsuperscript{2}Division of X \\ %
\textsuperscript{3}College of X
}
```

Comment: While your answer does not look particularly bad, notice that there is no space between "Author1^{1,2}," and "Author2". You should add some space there. Can you tell why somebody should use this instead of an `\and` between the two authors? And why do you use `\textsuperscript`? `\inst{1,2}` works as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Based on my experience, \and makes a larger space among affiliation lines. And, you are right, there is no difference in using \textsuperscript or \inst.

Comment: In that case you might at least add a normal space between the "," and "Author2" :)

Comment: I found this solution to work when the `\inst` command from the other solution crashed the compiler (MikTeX, Windows 10).