# Beamer title page: inserting 2 supervisors names with different universities

Tags: beamer, thesis

I would like to reproduce the file as shows the picture attached to this message, specially the part circled in red color. Thank you in advanced.[image]

This is the minimal working example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %slides
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage {textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bbding} %Checkmark
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\date{\today}

\title[Titre]{Titre}
\institute{Université}

\author[author1]{Student\inst{1}\\[1ex]  {\small supervisor1\inst{1} supervisor2\inst{2}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Insertion numéros de page et courte version du titre
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116112/36296

Comment: And this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17963/36296